# Cannot find database driver: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver

Tags: jdbc, liquibase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was following [getting started with liquibase on snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383724/getting-started-with-liquibase-on-snowflake) to set up Snowflake db connection to liquibase, but with the following liquibase.properties file:

```
driver: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
classpath: ./liquibase-snowflake-1.0.jar
url: jdbc:snowflake://XXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com
username: YYYYYYYYY
password: ZZZZZZZZZZ
changeLogFile: mySnowflakeChangeLog.xml
```

I get a Snowflake driver error from liquibase:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
```

I checked that the driver being used is the correct one mentioned on the official documentation https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html . This is on JDK 13.0.1 and liquibase 3.8.2.

What is going wrong here / any suggestions on a workaround? Thanks in advance!

Comment: But do you have the driver jar file in your classpath?

Comment: I do. To double confirm it, I moved the `classpath: ./liquibase-snowflake-1.0.jar` line up. And then playing around with the path. Wrong path leads to `{path} does not exist`. Right path moves to driver error above

Comment: That's not the snowflake JDBC driver jar. It's the liquibase extension for snoflake. You need to have the driver jar, otherwise there's no way to communicate with the database: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/snowflake-jdbc

Comment: Interesting, yep that worked. Thanks @JBNizet

Comment: Where we need to place this jar file?